# Use of the verb 'perfom'

Tags: grammar

In some of the literature, I've gone through while doing my research I came across a weird combination of the verb 'perform' with names of things. As for my knowledge, we use the verb 'perform' with a noun indicating an action. Such as, we can say:

perform an activity,
perform a pilgrimage, 
perform an act [polishing, brushing, etc]

but, can we say:

perform a bat,
perform a brush,
perform a polish,
perform a vacuum cleaner

I never believed so, but I need to have the consent of natives/ English users on this, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say those things.

A "bat" isn't an action that you can perform.  It is either a flying mammal or a piece of wood for hitting a ball.  The action you perform with a bat might be called a "stroke", or a "drive".

> Kumar showed me how to perform a batting stroke.
>
> Kumar performed a classic forward drive, but misread the spin and edged the ball to second slip.

Similarly a vacuum cleaner isn't an action.

We use "perform an action" with a complex action. Usually something that requires skill or effort to do well.  Polishing a ball is too simple.  But polishing a pair of boots might be okay, if you need to emphasise that it is a complex skill.

> How to perform the perfect polish of your leather boots, to army standard!

But even this would be unusual.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say those things.

A "bat" isn't an action that you can perform.  It is either a flying mammal or a piece of wood for hitting a ball.  The action you perform with a bat might be called a "stroke", or a "drive".

> Kumar showed me how to perform a batting stroke.
>
> Kumar performed a classic forward drive, but misread the spin and edged the ball to second slip.

Similarly a vacuum cleaner isn't an action.

We use "perform an action" with a complex action. Usually something that requires skill or effort to do well.  Polishing a ball is too simple.  But polishing a pair of boots might be okay, if you need to emphasise that it is a complex skill.

> How to perform the perfect polish of your leather boots, to army standard!

But even this would be unusual.

(There is one meaning of "bat" that is an action: the action of blinking at someone to attract their attention: "she turned to me and performed the perfect bat of her eyelids". This is still odd because blinking doesn't require much skill)